# Why does this regex find a match for \x63 with a pattern [\80-\BF]

Tags: regular-expression, unicode

I am trying to filter valid/invalid UTF-8 bytes, but I get strange results from the following regex (which is intended to handle a 3 byte form of UTF-8).

I have intended the pattern should **not** match the test bytes `'\xE0\xA1\x63'`, but it does...
What am I missing?

```
showmatch() {
  echo -ne "    --> "
  echo -ne "$bytes" | 
    # strip whitespace from the pattern
    perl -l -ne '/^'${1// /}'$/x and print' |
      tr -d '\n' |
        xxd -p |
          tr -d '\n'
  echo; 
}

bytes='\xE0\xA1\x63'
echo -n "before: "; echo -ne "$bytes" |xxd -p
# Note: all whitespace is stripped from each regex pattern.
#           Bytes 1 and 2 and 3
#          (---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------)
#              Bytes 1 and 2
#             (------------------------------------------------------------------------------)                  
#                [byt1][byt2-----]  |  [byt1][byt2-----]  |  [byte-1------------][byt2-----]      [byt3----]                                                          
#                =================     =================     ===============================      ==========                            
showmatch '(  ( ([\xE0][\xA0-\xBF]) | ([\xED][\x80-\x9F]) | ([\xE1-\xEC\xEE-\xEF][\x80-\xBF]) )  ([\80-\xBF])  )'
#
# witout spaces:
showmatch '((([\xE0][\xA0-\xBF])|([\xED][\x80-\x9F])|([\xE1-\xEC\xEE-\xEF][\x80-\xBF]))([\80-\xBF]))'
#
exit
```

---

Here is the output

```
before: e0a163
    --> e0a163
    --> e0a163
```

Comment: I reverted your subject line back to the original so we don't send people chasing a problem that is no longer written up as a problem. Also I would move your edit note from the top of the question to a comment. It's ok that it got solved by you shortly afterwards; the question can stay but leave the main question body as a question, comment on it here, and if need be provide an answer below (although it looks like that happened already)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you forgot an `x` in the last part of the regex:

```
[\80-\xBF]  -->  [\x80-\xBF]
```

Comment: :) thanks Andomar.... so simple.... As I've now mentioned in an edit in the question; actually writing and preparing the question gave me a fresh view.... I noticed a similar mistake in the question itslef.... I am soooooo relieved.... one and half days later :)

Answer (score 2):

You've spotted the mistake, good. What would be useful now is ways to spot similar mistakes or to avoid them in the future.

You've already hit on Perl's `x` modifier to the regexp operators, which lets you have whitespace in the regexps. Your matching construct would be written with newlines (which would let you add comments).

```
/(  ( ([\xE0][\xA0-\xBF]) |
      ([\xED][\x80-\x9F]) |
      ([\xE1-\xEC\xEE-\xEF][\x80-\xBF]) )
    ([\80-\xBF])  )/x
```

or without the parentheses that aren't necessary here:

```
/([\xE0][\xA0-\xBF]|
  [\xED][\x80-\x9F]|
  [\xE1-\xEC\xEE-\xEF][\x80-\xBF])
 [\80-\xBF] /x
```

I find that the missing `x` stands out more this way.

Comment: Ahhh..thanks Gilles, a good hint... I tried the `x` but I hadn't quite worked it out. I used a shell line ending, but that didn't work (maybe it was a trailing space..), so I used a quick 'sed' (I just forgot to remove the `x`), but come to think of it, it's pretty much the same as a quoted string, or braces spanning multiple lines. The `x` just tidies up